# New Post Update button

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-modal

```
<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 45px; cursor: pointer;"></i>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I make this button into a modal? Ive been working on this button and want to make to were a user can click and a modal view opens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing **data-toggle** and **data-target** attributes on the button:

```
data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"
```

- `data-toggle` describes *which type of bootstrap object* you're trying to toggle.

Other data-toggle examples are:

```
data-toggle="modal"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-toggle="dropdown"
data-toggle="tab"
```

- `data-target` targets the *specific object* you're trying to toggle, in this case #myModal.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<i class="fa fa-plus-square-o" aria-hidden="true" style="font-size: 45px; cursor: pointer;" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"></i>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a button say

```
 <button type="button" id="update-btn" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
```

outside your modal class Then in your `script` tag

```
   $('#update-btn').click(function()({
     $('#myModal').modal('show');
});
```

Comment: That's not a good practice, when the bootstrap framework already provides the necessary attributes to trigger the event. You're just making use of additional unecessary javascript.